Why my 'email' in LoginFormAuthenticator is 'null'?
Im trying to do 'remember me' feature in my applicaton (in Symfony 6).  I follow steps from 'https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/remember-me'. After all was done I got error during login (it didn't matter if I had checked 'remember me' checkbox or not):
'Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge::__construct(): Argument #1 ($userIdentifier) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\Users\pc\symfony6-film-collection\src\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator.php on line 49'
My function 'authenticate' in 'LoginFormAuthernticator.php' looks like this:
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {   
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $password = $request->request->get('password');

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email, function($userIdentifier) {
                // optionally pass a callback to load the User manually
                $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $userIdentifier]);

                if (!$user) {
                    throw new UserNotFoundException();
                }

                return $user;
            }),
            new PasswordCredentials($password),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge(
                    'authenticate',
                    $request->request->get('_csrf_token')
                ),
                new RememberMeBadge(),
            ]
        );
    }

And my 'security.yaml' part like this:
`providers:
app_user_provider:
entity:
class: App\Entity\User
property: email
firewalls:
main:
lazy: true
provider: app_user_provider
custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
form_login:
login_path: app_login
check_path: app_login
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_index

        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800`

In 'User' class I have set identifier correctly:
public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

And lastly my form (only the most important part) like this:
<form id="loginForm" action="{{ path('app_login') }}" method="POST">
(...)

<input 
    type="checkbox"
    id="rememberMeCheckbox"
    name="_remember_me"                      
>
(...)

Error occurs in this line (number 49): new UserBadge($email, function($userIdentifier) {}, but I still don't know why though. I dumbed 'email' variable before that line and actually 'email' is null. I guess the problem lies in 'security.yaml' file but I have no idea how to fix it. I know only this - when I uncommented custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator line, then I could login without problems although 'remember me' feature didn't work.
Any idea???
